# Substitute only in the matched part of a Perl pattern

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

How can I substitute only in matched pattern and put it back in same variable using Perl?

For example:

```
my $str = "a.b.AA pat1 BB hgf AA pat1 BB jkl CC pat1 don't change pat1";
```

I want to match `pat1` between `AA` and `BB` and replace it with Original string PAT2. However, I don't want to replace `pat1` anywhere else in the same string

Expected output string:

```
a.b.AA PAT2 BB hgf AA PAT2 BB jkl CC pat1 don't change pat1
```

I am sure there should be some good way to do it; please advise.

Original string:

```
my $ORG_str = 'A.B.C.\\valid.A .\\valid.A.B.C .\\valid.X.Y.Z .p.q.r.s';
```

Expected String:

```
my $EXP_op = 'A.B.C.\\valid?A .\\valid?A?B?C .\\valid?X?Y?Z .p.q.r.s';
```

Substitute character `.` to `?` only if it is between backslash `\` and whitespace .

Comment: Using capturing groups is the most simple.

Comment: Your original scenario might have been better shown by `"xxAA pat1 yy pat1 zz BB abc AA pp pat1 qq pat1 rr pat1 ssBB def pat1 ghi pat1"` or something like that.  Showing that multiple ocurrences of `pat1` can appear between the boundary markers AA and BB, along with other characters, would help clarify the problem.

Comment: I think I cleaned up the post. But, the answer overall question is exactly what the substitution operator does. I think the better question is "How do I retain parts of the matched pattern." Since it's retaining stuff on both sides, we don't get to use the `\K`. :(

Comment: @briandfoy Sorry for miscommunication.  Can you please advise some solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very simple with one single regexp, so I used divide and conquer to compute the result. This is a small recursive function that is replacing a single '.' per group of ('\' ' ')

The iteration ends when there is nothing to replace

```
sub replace {
    my ($input) = @_;

    my $result = $input;
    $result =~ s/(\\\S*?)\.(.*? )/$1?$2/g;
    return $result if $result eq $input;
    return replace($result);
}
```

The function with some test cases

```
use strict;

my $ORG_str= 'A.B.C.\\\\valid.A .\\\\valid.A.B.C .\\\\valid.X.Y.Z .p.q.r.s';
my $EXP_op ='A.B.C.\\\\valid?A .\\\\valid?A?B?C .\\\\valid?X?Y?Z .p.q.r.s';

sub replace {
    my ($input) = @_;

    my $result = $input;
    $result =~ s/(\\\S*?)\.(.*? )/$1?$2/g;
    return $result if $result eq $input;
    return replace($result);
}

my $check;
my $result;
my $expected;

$check = 'abcd'; $expected = $check;
$result = replace($check);
assert($result eq $expected, "'$check' gives '$expected'");

$check = 'ab\xxx. cd'; $expected = 'ab\xxx? cd';
$result = replace($check);
assert($result eq $expected, "'$check' gives '$expected'");

$check = 'ab\x.x.x. cd'; $expected = 'ab\x?x?x? cd';
$result = replace($check);
assert($result eq $expected, "'$check' gives '$expected'");

$check = 'ab\x.x.x. cd\y.y.y.'; $expected = 'ab\x?x?x? cd\y.y.y.';
$result = replace($check);
assert($result eq $expected, "'$check' gives '$expected'");

$check = 'ab\x.x.x. cd\xxx.xxx..xxx...x \y.y.y.'; $expected = 'ab\x?x?x? cd\xxx?xxx??xxx???x \y.y.y.';
$result = replace($check);
assert($result eq $expected, "'$check' gives '$expected'");

$check = '. ..\.. ...\.. ...\.. ...\..'; $expected = '. ..\?? ...\?? ...\?? ...\..';
$result = replace($check);
assert($result eq $expected, "'$check' gives '$expected'");


$check = $ORG_str; $expected = $EXP_op; 
$result = replace($check);
assert($result eq $expected, "'$check' gives '$expected'");


sub assert {
    my ($cond, $mesg) = @_;
    print "checking $mesg ... ";
    die "\nFAIL: $mesg" unless $cond;
    print "OK\n";
}
```

The result

```
checking 'abcd' gives 'abcd' ... OK
checking 'ab\xxx. cd' gives 'ab\xxx? cd' ... OK
checking 'ab\x.x.x. cd' gives 'ab\x?x?x? cd' ... OK
checking 'ab\x.x.x. cd\y.y.y.' gives 'ab\x?x?x? cd\y.y.y.' ... OK
checking 'ab\x.x.x. cd\xxx.xxx..xxx...x \y.y.y.' gives 'ab\x?x?x? cd\xxx?xxx??xxx???x \y.y.y.' ... OK
checking '. ..\.. ...\.. ...\.. ...\..' gives '. ..\?? ...\?? ...\?? ...\..' ... OK
checking 'A.B.C.\\valid.A .\\valid.A.B.C .\\valid.X.Y.Z .p.q.r.s' gives 'A.B.C.\\valid?A .\\valid?A?B?C .\\valid?X?Y?Z .p.q.r.s' ... OK
```

Comment: old answer deleted ;)

Answer (score 4):

Look into [look-around regexes](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444).

```
s/(?<=AA )pat1(?= BB)/pat2/g
```

This matches and replaces a `pat1` surrounded by `AA` and `BB`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\\\\[^. ]*\K|(?!^)\G\.([^. ]*)
```

You can try this.Replace by `?$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/28

The resultant string will not be exactly same as you want but you can easily do a clean up.

```
\?(?=\?)
```

Replace by `empty string` and you have what you want.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/29